# How do I make NLTK pos_tag words instead of characters?

Tags: python, nltk

I have this code to find nouns and verbs in a sentence.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk import pos_tag
import nltk
syno =[]


sentence = '''His father suggested he study to become a parson instead, but Darwin was far more inclined to study natural history.DarwinDar·win (där'wĭn),Charles Robert.1809-1882.British naturalist who revolutionized the study of biology with his theory ofevolutionbased on natural selection
Like several scientists before him, Darwin believed all the life on earth evolved (developed gradually) over millions of years from a few common ancestors.'''

sent = pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
```

This returns

```
[('H', 'NNP'), ('e', 'VBP'), ('l', 'NN'), ('l', 'NN'), ('o', 'NN'), (' ', ':'), ('m', 'NN'), ('y', 'NN'), (' ', ':'), ('n', 'NN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('m', 'NN'), ('e', 'NN'), (' ', ':'), ('i', 'PRP'), ('s', 'VBZ'), (' ', ':'), ('A', 'DT'), ('b', 'NN'), ('h', 'NN'), ('i', 'PRP'), ('s', 'VBZ'), ('h', 'JJ'), ('e', 'NN'), ('k', 'NN'), (' ', ':'), ('M', 'NNP'), ('i', 'PRP'), ('t', 'VBP'), ('r', 'JJ'), ('a', 'DT')]
```

I want it to operate on words though, not characters! How do I do this?

Answer (score 9):

You need to tokenize first:

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> sentence = "Hello my name is Derek. I live in Salt Lake city."
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
[('Hello', 'NNP'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('name', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('Derek.', 'NNP'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('live', 'VBP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('Salt', 'NNP'), ('Lake', 'NNP'), ('city', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the sentence. Now how can i remove only the NN words.

Comment: @user2675742: by a list comprehension? This is basic Python, you'll find it in the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Comment: I get 'NameError: name 'word_tokenize' is not defined'. I have edited my code.